# Start server after stuck at GRUB

Tags: grub2, headless

I currently have Ubuntu Server 14.04 and sometimes when I reboot it gets stuck on grub selection without countdown. It is the same problem as [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/243343/headless-ubuntu-server-machine-sometimes-stuck-at-grub-menu), but I want to fix it remotely because I am not home right now...

I know that it is a long shot, but is there any solution or workaround so that I can boot to my server without being physically there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add:
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT = 15
in /etc/default/grub, and run "sudo update-grub".  You can change the 15 to any arbitrary number of seconds that you like.

Comment: I currently can't boot at the system so that I can change the grub config. Right now is stuck at grub and I can't do anything...

Comment: Then you are out of luck.